# SourceUnavailableError when requesting getUserMedia for video from about: page

Tags: firefox-addon

Requesting mic with `audio:true` works perfectly fine, however requesting webcam video, or screen video is failing with `SourceUnavailbleError`. I have added the string of `browser` to the preference `media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains`

Code for requesting webcam video:

```
        var param = {
            // audio: true, // if just this it works fine
            video: true // {mediaSource: 'screen'} does not work either
        };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(param).then(function(stream) {
            console.log('success');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error('err:', err)
        });
```

To reproduce this error, open up browser console, and paste the code above like this:

[image]

Error given is:

`err: MediaStreamError { name: "SourceUnavailableError", message: "Failed to allocate videosource", constraint: "", stack: "" }`

Do you know how I can get around this `SourceUnvailableError`?

I did a lot of digging here - https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/modules/webrtcUI.jsm#201 - but no success yet.

Thanks

Comment: Noitidart, you know that your source code needs to be in the question for debugging questions and that it should be a [MCVE]. Please put it in the question. The github link is nice, but it is not what the question requires.

Comment: @Noitidart i cannot reproduce it.i got success message.do you have a videosource/camera when you test it

Comment: according to wc3 `The source of the MediaStream could not be accessed due to a hardware error (e.g. lock from another process).`did you open another application which use camera

Comment: Thanks very much @FastSnail for that. That is true, if another process is using it will give that, I verifieid on IRC. I restarted my computer and the first thing I used was this, and it gave same error. So it is very confusing. Did you try with `{mediaSource:'screen'}`?

Comment: @Noitidart gaves me `name: "SecurityError"`.after i change config screenSharingdomains it works.i got success

Comment: Wow very interesting. Thanks @FastSnail ! It seems this error I'm getting is only on some computers. By the way what did you update the screen sharing config to? Did you add `browser`? Or `gre-resources`?

Comment: @Noitidart i update `media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains` to `*`.i think i need reset it now